# How can I select columns based on a control file with invalid column numbers?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv

I have to generate the file dynamically from the source file based on the below control file.

```
control_file.txt 
1,3,5,-1,8,-1,4
```

The control file contains the position of columns which I require from the source file.

Example: 1 column, 3 column, 5 column, blank column (-1 indicates blank column) and so on..

I have written a shell to read the position from the control file, one by one, to generate multiple files. Then finally use the paste command to generate new files, incase of -1 values I created touch files. Based on sequence of file order, it is pasted by `ls-v` option.

So my existing shell looks like below:

```
if [ position != -1 ]
then
cut -d, -f$position > file_$var.csv 
else
touch file_$var.csv
fi
paste -d, $(ls -v file_*.csv) > newe_file.csv
```

I hope there is a way to minimize the I/O of files, I am looking for something below:

```
cut -d, -f1,3,5 > file1.csv
touch file2.csv
cut -d, -f8 > file3.csv
touch file4.csv
cut -d, -f4 > file5.csv
```

Or better solution will be great.

The number of columns in the source files will be in the hundreds.

Expected results:

```
input-file is sample.csv

col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
```

output.csv:

```
col1,col3,col5,-1,col8,-1,col4
1,3,5,,8,,4
9,11,13,,16,,12
```

output.csv is based on `controlfile.txt`

Comment: this look like code golf, can you show use expected result ?

Comment: @Archemar please find the expected details. If required i will share the entire script which i have written.Thanks

Comment: CSV files can have newlines in the elements, elements can be quoted or not and the separater is can default to a different character than `,`. All in all best handled with a programming language like python/ruby/perl with an appropriate CSV handling library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer, a little simpler than the others:

```
#!/bin/bash
fields=$(sed -r -e 's/-1/ /g' -e 's/,/ FS /g' \
  -e 's/([0-9]+)/\$\1/g' control_file.txt)
awk -F, "{print ${fields}}" $1
```

The first command converts `control_file.txt` into a suitable `awk` command:

```
$1 FS $3 FS $5 FS FS $8 FS FS $4
```

to run it:

```
$ ./script.sh input.csv
col1,col3,col5,,col8,,col4
1,3,5,,8,,4
9,11,13,,16,,12
```

On your other sample:

```
$ ./script.sh sample.csv
BP ID,CurrentMonetary balance ,Provider contract id,,End Date,,charge Plan names 
1100001538,251,00000000000000000141,,18-Oct-12,,[B2] R2 LTE CHARGE PLAN 
1100003404,45.22,00000000000000009349,,23-Nov-13,,B0.3 ECS_CHARGE_PLAN DROP1 V3
```

Comment: $Sebastian fields are assigned with values as mentioned but awk is not printing the desired values. plz help me..

Comment: what is the error? have you called `./script.sh input.csv` with the `input.csv` as provided above?

Comment: BP ID,Prepaid Account No,CurrentMonetary balance ,charge Plan names ,Provider contract id,Contract Item ID,Start Date,End Date
1100001538,001000002506,251,[B2] R2 LTE CHARGE PLAN ,00000000000000000141,[B2] R2 LTE CHARGE PLAN _00155D10E20D1ED39A8E146EA7169A2E00155D10E20D1ED398FD63624498DB4A,16-Oct-12,18-Oct-12
1100003404,001000004029,45.22,B0.3 ECS_CHARGE_PLAN DROP1 V3,00000000000000009349,B0.3 ECS  DROP2 V0.2_00155D10E20D1ED39A8E146EA7169A2E00155D10E20D1ED398FD63624498DA2E,16-Nov-13,23-Nov-13
My sample data can you please test with this ?

Comment: 18ct-12 1100003404 values are wrong right also , i am getting answer like below, sh test1.sh control.txt sample.csv
,,Provider contract idbalance ,End Date
,,0000000000000000014112
,,00000000000000009349v-13
,,00000000000000010477Nov-13

Comment: another thing: check if there is really a **ascii** comma in your file: The one between `16-Nov-13` and `​23-Nov-1` is not! it's hexdump is `c32c c2a2 c280 c38c c2a2 c280 0a8b`

Comment: Thanks you very much @Sebastian my source file is mesh i guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8' |
sed 's/[^,]*//7;s///6;s///2;s/,,/,/
    s/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),,.*,\(.*\)/\2,,\3,,\1/'
```

That removes the contents of fields 7,6,2. Next it removes the first blank field. Then it swaps the last three nonempty fields like 2,,3,,1.

#### OUTPUT

```
1,3,5,,8,,4
```

And run on your sample data:

```
BP ID,CurrentMonetary balance ,Provider contract id,,End Date,,charge Plan names 
1100001538,251,00000000000000000141,,18-Oct-12,,[B2] R2 LTE CHARGE PLAN 
1100003404,45.22,00000000000000009349,,23-Nov-13,,B0.3 ECS_CHARGE_PLAN DROP1 V3
```

Then again, as long as you can verify your delimiter, you *can* just use the shell:

```
set -f; IFS=,
set -- $(cat file; echo "$IFS")
while [ $# -gt 8 ]
do printf %s\\n "$1,$3,$5,,$8,,$4"
   shift "$(($#>7?8:$#))"
done
```

With the shell option the fields can contain anything but the delimiter. As long as you have a delimiter that is other than `<space><tab><newline>` empty fields will be preserved. Any characters they contain - to include any of those three whitespace characters - are preserved. Here I use a comma. You need only enough memory to fit the file.

Comment: wow :) yes, this matches my output. btw, if you use `sed -r` you can avoid some backslashes,e.g. `\( \)` becomes `()`. However, I doubt that this makes your regex more readable ;-) `sed -r 's/[^,]*//7;s///6;s///2;s/,,/,/;s/([^,]*),([^,]*),,.*,(.*)/\2,,\3,,\1/' input.csv`

Comment: @Sebastian - dont use `sed -r` - if you *must* use `-E` - it will soon be POSIX i think. but if the cost is a couple of backslashes typed and the purchase is the script working or not working... i'll pay the backslashes. know what i mean? and its pretty readable - remove fields 7 6 2, remove first blank field, swap last nonempty three fields - 2 3 1

Comment: point accepted.

Comment: @Sebastian but, to be fair, there is a lot of `\\\///,,,((()))` 8 in between. It reads like a lunch menu to me now, but i remember what it used to look like too.

Comment: Will it works for any file ? means any number of fields ?

Comment: @WilliamR - oh no - only 8 comma delimited-fields per line. It will work for any number of *lines* - is that what you mean?

Comment: @mikenserv No Sir it has to be dynamic in fields. As suugested by Sebastian.

Comment: @WilliamR the shell option will work with any number of fields and does not need the file.

Comment: Thanks you very much @mikeserv my source file is mesh i guess.

Answer (score 0):

the awk file

```
BEGIN { sp="-1" ;  FS="," ; }
FILENAME == "control.txt" { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) col[i]=$i ;  next ;}
FILENAME != "control.txt" {
    comma="" ;
    for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {
            c=col[i] ;
            if (col[i]!=-1) printf "%s%s",comma,$c ;
            else printf "%s%s",comma,sp ;
            comma="," ;
    }
    printf "\n" ;
    sp="" ;
    }
```

the run

```
 awk -f a.awk control.txt  sample.txt
 col1,col3,col5,-1,col8,-1,col4
 1,3,5,,8,,4
 9,11,13,,16,,12
```

basically,  first line in control.txt get wich column to print.